# How to fix distorted text with small font size in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, text, scale

I'm building an small application with JavaFX to visualize circuit boards. The application includes the possibility of scaling and shifting. When I display small texts, they are distorted, as you can see on the screenshots below. Only when I have zoomed far enough into the scene will the text be displayed correctly again. Does anyone have a solution to this problem? I included the example code from which the screenshots are taken.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    addMouseEventHandler(root);

    Pane pane1 = new Pane();
    Text text1 = new Text(400, 400, "Text 1");
    text1.setFont(new Font(5));
    pane1.getChildren().addAll(text1);
    root.getChildren().add(pane1);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Text scaling problem");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 800));
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void addMouseEventHandler(Pane root) {
    // add scroll handling to zoom in and out
    root.setOnScroll((event) ->
    {
        double factor = event.getDeltaY() > 0 ? 1.1 : 0.9;
        root.setScaleX(root.getScaleX() * factor);
        root.setScaleY(root.getScaleY() * factor);
    });

    // add drag handling
    root.setOnMousePressed((mouseEvent) ->
    {
        startMouseX = mouseEvent.getSceneX();
        startMouseY = mouseEvent.getSceneY();

        startTranslationX = root.getTranslateX();
        startTranslationY = root.getTranslateY();
    });

    root.setOnMouseDragged((mouseEvent) ->
    {
        double movedX = startMouseX - mouseEvent.getSceneX();
        double movedY = startMouseY - mouseEvent.getSceneY();

        double transX = startTranslationX - movedX;
        double transY = startTranslationY - movedY;

        root.setTranslateX(transX);
        root.setTranslateY(transY);
    });
}
```

[correct text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frP4X.jpg)
vs
[distorted text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZJ6J.jpg)

The correct text is scrolled one more step than the distorted.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if anything can be done about scaling of text inside of the text node. but if you separate the characters in different text nodes it will keep its shape. you might wanna try Canvas and manually draw using GraphicsContext2D.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DistortedText extends Application{

    private double startMouseX, startMouseY;
    private double startTranslationX, startTranslationY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox box = new HBox(new Text("T"),new Text("e"),new Text("x"),new Text("T"),new Text(" "),new Text("1"));

        Pane root = new Pane(box);
        addMouseEventHandler(root,box);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Text scaling problem");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 800));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void addMouseEventHandler( Pane container, Node node) {
        // add scroll handling to zoom in and out
        container.setOnScroll((event) ->
        {
            double factor = event.getDeltaY() > 0 ? 1.1 : 0.9;
            node.setScaleX(node.getScaleX() * factor);
            node.setScaleY(node.getScaleY() * factor);
        });

        // add drag handling
        container.setOnMousePressed((mouseEvent) ->
        {
            startMouseX = mouseEvent.getX();
            startMouseY = mouseEvent.getY();

            startTranslationX = node.getTranslateX();
            startTranslationY = node.getTranslateY();
        });

        container.setOnMouseDragged((mouseEvent) ->
        {
            double movedX = startMouseX - mouseEvent.getX();
            double movedY = startMouseY - mouseEvent.getY();

            double transX = startTranslationX - movedX;
            double transY = startTranslationY - movedY;

            node.setTranslateX(transX);
            node.setTranslateY(transY);
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch( args);
    }
}
```